# Implementation conflicts between protocols

Tags: swift, oop, inheritance, protocols, implementation

I've stumbled upon an issue, and I can not figure out how am I going to solve it.

Let's suppose we have a base class (that may comes from FrameworkA), with a property named `subject`:

```
public class MyClass {
    public var subject: String
}
```

And we have a protocol (that may comes from FrameworkB), with another property but with the same name:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
    var subject: String { get }
}
```

**Those two properties represent totally different things.**

How can I create a class that inherits from `MyClass` and implements `MyProtocol`?
And how can I use these properties?

```
public class SecondClass: MyClass, MyProtocol {
    var MyProcotol.name: String { // <==== Obviously not allowed
        return "something"
    }
    var MyClass.name: String { // <==== Obviously not allowed
        return "something else"
    }
}
```

I think that C# allows some kind of declaration like this, but I'm not 100% sure...

Comment: You need to name things accordingly. If they are different you need different names.

Comment: Yes, of course :)
But, what if I can't do anything about it, for example, the base class and the protocol are part of some frameworks (even separate frameworks) ?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I disagree with you, it is a very good question, the solution isn't set the name of the things accordingly always, things like this can be happen and the language(compiler) must be have a solution

Comment: Ok, so to fix the problem you send a bug report to Apple and wait a few years. That's not helping. What helps is if anyone declaring a protocol uses sensible names, and then you name your methods accordingly.

Comment: Yep, framework developers should use sensible names. But app developers also should stop having single classes trying to achieve too many disparate (and in this case conflicting) purposes.

Comment: @VictorSigler I did not say it's a bad question. I was just telling it's not possible with Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, for a moment let's look at the problem from the point of view of the code that does use these classes and let's ignore how they are implemented.

### Fact 1

If **secondClass** : SecondClass extends `MyClass` then I expect to be able to write:

```
secondClass.subject
```

### Fact 2

If `secondClass` conforms to `MyProtocol` then I expect to be able to write

```
secondClass.subject
```

If we create a different way for `secondClass` to expose `MyClass.subject` and `MyProtocol.subject` we are breaking the Object Oriented Paradigm.

### Infact

1. When you extend a class, you implicitly inherit the all non private properties and methods, you cannot (and this is a good thing) rename them.
2. When you conform to a protocol you expose all the non optional declared properties and methods exactly as they are described in the protocol

If `SecondClass` renamed the 2 properties like in your pseudo-code, we would not be able to write something like this.

```
let list : [MyClass] = [MyClass(), SecondClass()]

for elm in list {
    println(elm.subject)
}
```

### A possible (partial) solution

You should avoid the **is-a** approach in favor of the **has-a**.

```
class SecondClass {
    let myClass : MyClass
    let somethingElse : MyProtocol

    init(myClass : MyClass, somethingElse:MyProtocol) {
        self.myClass = myClass
        self.somethingElse = somethingElse
    }

    var myClassSubject : String { get { return myClass.subject } }
    var myProtocolSubject : String { get { return somethingElse.subject } }
}
```

Now since

1. `SecondClass` **is not** a `MyClass` and
2. `SecondClass` **is not** a `MyProtocol`

It has not the **`subject`** property removing any risk of confusion.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Victor Sigler: thank you for the better formatting!

Comment: I like your answer, but I think Apple need to correct this in future releases of Swift, because the compiler must be know how to deal with this kind of situations.

Comment: The problem here is that we are dealing with a conceptual constraint related to OOP. I really don't how the language itself could be changed to manage this kind of scenario.

Comment: The original proposal for traits [Traits: Composable Units of Behaviour](http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/papers/Scha03aTraits.pdf) describes tools for such conflict resolutions which include *alias* and *exclusion* of methods (see 3.5 Conflict Resolution). Might be interested to you ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over this base class and/or the protocol, you can give the properties unique names and that solves the problem.

If you cannot do that, the question becomes whether `SecondClass` really has to fulfill these two conflicting responsibilities itself. Specifically, what is `MyProtocol`? Some delegate protocol? You could instead have `SecondClass` vend a separate object that conforms to that protocol, eliminating the conflicting dual roles.

Bottom line, rather than having a single object attempt serve two conflicting purposes, split the responsibilities into separate objects resolving any such conflict.